# Urgent tips for UK Visit Visa application for a student and how to prove strong ties with my country?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I am applying to UK for the visit visa. I have just taken my A-level exams and awaiting for my results, and I have already enrolled into a university in my country, Pakistan. I've no property, or source of income and my uncle in the UK is sponsoring (he has given me the sponsorship letter) the whole trip for mine. I want to ask that, apart from the University admission letter, what should I attach with my documents to prove that I will return back to my country. Moreover, in  the application form a question specifically asks that I have any other source of income such as getting monthly income from my parents. I'm a bit confused because although my parents don't give me any fixed income monthly, they pay for my education, food and others; so should I write no source of income, or write that I get fixed amount of income ( I don't have any documents to prove that ). Moreover, I have already visited UK once in the 2007 for summer holidays already.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you don't _have_ strong ties to prove ...

Comment: It might be helpful to have your parents write something about their plan to support you during university studies in your home county, and detailing their finances. That adds to the picture of having both family ties and a viable plan to continue your education at home on return from the UK.

Comment: My father is a government employee as well as own many properties. He has visited Uk twice before, like 7 years before. Should I ask him to write a letter, stating his stable financial background as well as his income. I will submit the income tax documents, and his pay slips too. Will that be enough?

Comment: You do not get strong ties to your homeland just because your father is wealthy. It means he has strong ties, but says nothing about YOU as an individual.  In fact it can actually undermine your claim to strong ties because he can send you money to live illegally in the UK just as easily. The ties have to be your own, not your father's.

Comment: Thanks Gayot for answering. Again, I'm confused regarding what to attach and what not to attach to strengthen my application. In my situation, I think I can only attach my university enrollment letter, my past travel history and my great academic record (9A*1A in GCSE's). I was wondering if I got rejected for visit visa to UK, then would it become very difficult for me to get visit visa in the future for the UK, or any other European country?

Comment: It won't become difficult, it is just a point that will be considered in future applications. Most applications are usually considered on their own merits. The exceptions are in the cases of deception or suspected criminal activity. As long as you are honest and just give the best supporting documents you can, if they say no, they say no. If yes, then enjoy your visit.

Comment: Anything from your father should be in the context of the shared plan to continue your education in Pakistan. Showing he is wealthy is not, in itself, useful. Showing he plans to support your education at the university where you have enrolled, and has the means to do so, gives you a reason to return to Pakistan after your visit.